# mingw dw2 exceptions on x64

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, x86-64

I'm using Clang to compile some code on Windows. To support this I've used libstdc++ from MinGW. But now I'm looking at compiling for 64bit instead of 32bit and I can only seem to find SEH or SJLJ exception models. Are there no Itanium ABI exceptions for Windows x64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, MinGW does not support DW2 exceptions for 64-bit.

For 64-bit, you want to use SEH exceptions, which is superior to both SJLJ and DW2. SEH exceptions are low overhead when no exception is thrown (like DW2), and *also* low overhead when an exception is thrown, and don't take excessive space.

In fact, because of its advantages you would *actually* always want to use SEH exceptions, even under 32-bit, but unluckily there is no 32-bit support due to a US patent held by Borland (5,628,016).

Though I would soon expect 32-bit support to be implemented, as this patent was filed June 15, 1994 and issued May 6, 1997. which, if I'm reading the *"applications filed before June 8, 1995"* rule right, would mean that it is valid for 17 years after the issue date (May 8, 2014) or 20 years from the filing date (June 15, 2014), whichever is longer.
In other words, the patent should have expired exactly a month ago.

Comment: Any technological superiority is lost on me if Clang does not support it. (Also, the x86 version of SEH is very different to x64, that much I do know).